# Does Heroku create a unique instance of my app for each user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, spotify

I created a simple Heroku app that does the following:

- Asks a user to log in to Spotify
- After they are successfully authenticated, it pulls all bands in
  their Spotify playlists and stores it in an array
- The user then presses a button called "Show me my bands". This button
  makes an Ajax call to /bands (shown below) which compares the user's Spotify band list to a mongoDB and displays their band information.

**Problem**: This code works great for me. However, when a friend then logs into his Spotify and taps "Show me my bands" - it shows him *my* band list.

**Question**: Do you know why this is happening? <strike>Is there a way for Heroku to create a separate instance of my app for each user so that /bands is unique to each user?</strike>

Here's the code for /bands:

```
app.get('/bands', function(req, res) {

  // Search for bands in our database
  Band.find({name: { $in: unique}}).exec(function (err, docs){
  if(err) throw err;
  res.json(docs);
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does it create unqiue instances? No it does not, nor is this how the web works. Explaining that too you is far to broad to cover here. Perhaps do some searching and reading. Topics to look at are "logged in users" and "sessions".

Comment: Thanks Blakes, and apologies if my question didn't make sense. I'm fairly new to web development so still trying to understand what's actually going on. Found this [link](https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions/) that looks like it'll help me understand sessions better. Cheers!